# Circular Dependencies in C? I don't see it

Tags: c

I am new to C. I have a simple code here that for some reason is being claimed to have Circular dependacies

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int feet, fathoms;

    fathoms = 2;
    feet = 6 * fathoms;
    printf("there are %d feet in %d fathoms!\n", feet, fathoms);
    return 0;

}
```

It says something about

```
Circular 1<-1.o dependency dropped
Circular 2Fathoms <- 2Fathoms.o dependency dropped.
```

I've seen some in my other programming stuff... but I don't get it.

I am using bloodshed... is that a problem? haha.

Comment: Show your whole code.

Comment: That is my whole code.

Comment: Which compiler / command line are you using?  This code compiles and executes as expected for me using gcc and msvc

Comment: Take a look at this, could be your makefile?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/665180/why-is-make-complaining-about-circular-dependencies

Comment: how do you compile it? Use just `gcc file.c`

Comment: [Works fine](http://ideone.com/mt6zeN).

Comment: I am using Bloodshed... I don't know if that is the issue.. but I am at work so I wanted to use something small.

Comment: @Chris [TCC](http://bellard.org/tcc/) is quite small, and less ancient.

Comment: I think it might be bloodshed's fault. What other recommendations are there?

Comment: @kninnug whenI started it, it just showed a command prompt for like half a second and went away.

Comment: Looks like a  `makefile` issue.  Manually delete any *.o files made and re-build. (Double check your make file rules.)

Answer (score 1):

After Learning that bloodshead has some issues, I switched to code::blocks and it worked perfectly.